# Toggle left animation without adding display:none

Tags: jquery, animation, toggle

I am trying to create an animate sliding navigation menu, where the submenu slides out using an animation toggle for the 'left' attribute.

I have successfully managed to get the left attribute to toggle between the initial setting of -360px, where the div is hidden and the 0 attribute where it is expanded out, but when the left attribute toggles to 0, it also adds display:none.

I think there should be a fairly simple solution but as yet I have not been able to find it

Here is the page where it is implemented

And here is the Jquery function:

http://alexpeake.info/index

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#gallerytoggle").click(function(){
    $("#travelling_info").animate({left:'toggle'},"slow");
  });

})
```

Comment: Can you also describe why you don't want to use *display: none;*?

Comment: Also, double click on the arrow. It screws up your layout. I'd consider fixing that too.

Comment: I don't want display none because the functionality I want is for the div to just slide out to reveal a submenu and then slide in again when reclicked, not slide out and disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it manually. Not sure if it's optimal, but it's my naive way of doing it:

```
var state = 1;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#gallerytoggle").click(function(){
    $("#travelling_info").animate({left: parseInt((state % 2 - 1) * (-360)) + 'px'}, "slow");
    state++;
  });    
});
```

Comment: When I tried this the div moved further left and just alternated between this third position and the second, rather than between the original and the second

Comment: fixed with a small change to your code thanks

-360 should have been 360